# InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0

Tags: mysql, xampp

I need some help with MySql in xampp 3.2.1. The MySql Service won't start and I couldn't find the reason why because the error log file reports that it cannot read from an 'unknown file' and only returns the error 0. 
I don't know what that means since it's basically saying that there is 0 error when it tries to read the unknown file.
Here's the error log:

```
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-01-20 10:36:12 574 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 131153885 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-01-20 10:36:12 760 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the exact same issue - running the same version of XAMPP and it just started happening around the same time as your issue.

Try this. Open up your XAMPP directory and go to XAMPP/mysql/Data

cut all of the files (ibdata*, auto.cnf, mysql.pid) and put them somewhere else.

Try to start up Mysql - if that works great, if not, what you may have to do, is look in your log which DB is giving you an issue - and move that corresponding folder as well.

with luck, that will fix your problem - well it worked for me!

Comment: thanks for the reply Bren1818, wish it had come sooner. I already re-installed my xampp, and sadly some of my unbackuped databases with it. :(

Comment: you must never delete ibdata - all your InnoDB tables will be lost

Comment: @noonex - thats why I said cut (move) not delete

Comment: following on https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mysql-database-is-not-starting-since-today-morning.343788/ by CIJ

i do this 
2) backup & remove both ib_logfile0 & ib_logfile1 files under --> /var/lib/mysql

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

This is for a different error code but see if it works.

Open MySQL config file by “Config” —> “my.ini”.

Insert
`innodb_flush_method = normal`

between 
`innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50` and `## UTF 8 Settings`

Start MySQL again in xampp.

https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=72437

Comment: Great solution, fix my problem straight away!

Comment: fixed mine too.